# How can I render img in Sanity Portable Text

Tags: vue.js

I used   render text ,but  i  render img it will be
this ,how to make it work

> [   {
> "_key": "7f16695776af",
> "_type": "image",
> "asset": {
> "_ref": "image-709f753904446711f664b160ac205b9f9ada6b4b-960x960-png",
> "_type": "reference"
> }   },   {
> "_key": "e6c81237bc58",
> "_type": "block",
> "children": [
> {
> "_key": "6cb2873619960",
> "_type": "span",
> "marks": [],
> "text": ""
> }
> ]

- 

Comment: this represent <image></image>

Comment: I used SanityBlocks